# Too Many Custom Fields show up in form

Tags: custom-fields

We have created a Custom Data Group call Certifications. The Certification fields are 5 multi-select check boxes.

The problem is when we create more than 22 of these Certification Data Fields, then when editing the fields for a specific Contact, we lose the View/Edit field at the far right, and the actual certification data fields don't show up.

I think this is more of a FORM/web-page problem than a DB issue. I see there is an issue (https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/1330) where more than 92 custom fields is an issue. This problem shows up with 23 custom data fields.

Presumably I can work around the problem by break up our data into different Certification Categories. But thought I would point out the issue here, to see if anyone has suggestions.
Here are the screen shots that show the problem. Thanks in advance. 
[image: failure mode]
[image: works with only 22 items]

Answer (score 1):

I switched from the Certification field being a TAB (in Contacts) to INLINE, and now the certification list is a VERTICAL list inside the Contact form and it works. And I like it better.

However, side-note, we have a hard limit of 63 custom fields in the Certification group. I think this is an SQL Join limit (we are using Civi-Spark).